# Laravel. errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I have a user information table :

```
Schema::create('user_information', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('full_name');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('nationality');
            $table->integer('profession_id');
            $table->string('university');
            $table->string('academic_degree');
            $table->string('company')->nullable();
            $table->integer('country_id');
            $table->string('phone_number');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->integer('age')->nullable();
            $table->string('photo_url')->nullable();
            $table->integer('company_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('social_network_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

and in other migration i update the table specifically the foreign keys:

```
Schema::table('user_information', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->change();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('profession_id')->change();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('country_id')->change();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('company_id')->nullable()->change();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('social_network_id')->nullable()->change();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('register_type_id')->nullable()->change();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('profession_id')->references('id')->on('profession');
            $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('country');
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('company');
            $table->foreign('social_network_id')->references('id')->on('social_network');
            $table->foreign('register_type_id')->references('id')->on('register_type');
        });
```

However when I run the migration I get the next error code:

```
Migrating: 2021_06_03_155507_update_foreign_keys

In Connection.php line 678:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `civgeo`.`user_information` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `user
  _information` add constraint `user_information_profession_id_foreign` foreign key (`profession_id`) references `profession` (`id`))


In Connection.php line 471:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `civgeo`.`user_information` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

All tables used as foreign keys have been created before the **user information** table

Comment: Are the column changes to unsignedBigInteger because the columns in the foreign key tables are unsignedBigInteger? If so, you may need to create 2 migrations, the first one to change the columns, the second to add the foreign keys. My thoughts are the column datatype changes aren't committed to the DB when the foreign keys are added.

Answer (score 0):

OK it was my mistake
My error was that in the foreign tables I declared the keys as

```
this->incrementes('id');
```

When I should have declared it as

```
this->id();
```